# Dynamically changing custom distribution

Tags: anylogic

I have created custom distribution in my model using option list.
[image]

First column is account ID. There are 3 types of account  High , Low , Medium .

I want to create  different scenarios in the model.

1. if user selects the High type of accounts then agents with High type should get generated at the source. Currently all agents with all account type are generated.
2. for a particular account type I want to change the custom distribution. e.g if user selects High type of account then the custom distribution for those account will be changed dynamically.
   If below two accounts are High type then I want to change the distribution using percentage

> ```
> before --->>
> Account      No of Observation        
> A-3929180    10
> A-5414929    20
> ```

Let's increase the distribution by 50%

> ```
> After--->>
> Account      No of Observation        
> A-3929180    15
> A-5414929    30
> ```

[image]

I couldn't see any help around creating custom distribution using Option list in Java.

Comment: can you refine this to the actual core question, it is a lot of "fluff". What exactly are you looking for? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To build a customDistribution that you change during simulation runtime in any way, you can do it yourself by definining it as follows:

```
new CustomDistributionOfOptions(OptionList.values(),new double[] { 34.0, 4.0, 5.0,  })
```

this is how you construct it programatically... so you have to create a variable of type CustomDistributionOfOptions and then set up a value for it as I mentionned.

The following can be an example of a function you might want to use to change your custom distribution:

```
double [] values=new double[OptionList.values().length];
int i=0;
for(OptionList o : OptionList.values()){
    values[i++]=uniform(1,15);
}
customDist=new CustomDistributionOfOptions(OptionList.values(),values);
```

Comment: I added a variable of type  customDistributionOfOptions . Below is the output I am getting Random number generator: Not set. I am getting option list with values as output . I just want only one value to be generated randomly

Comment: there's no output below